# Get display value from combobox in radgridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, combobox, telerik

I am using Telerik's RadGridView to display some data.  One of the columns in this gridview is a combobox, which is populated like so:

```
DataTable dtContractorName = A133DB.GetContractorsForCombo(true);
GridViewComboBoxColumn contractorNameColumn = new GridViewComboBoxColumn();
contractorNameColumn.UniqueName = "ContractorID";
contractorNameColumn.HeaderText = "Contractor";
contractorNameColumn.DataSource = dtContractorName;
contractorNameColumn.ValueMember = "ContractorID";
contractorNameColumn.DisplayMember = "ContractorName";
contractorNameColumn.FieldName = "ContractorID";
radGvReviews.Columns.Add(contractorNameColumn);
```

This works just fine for displaying the data properly in the gridview, but I would like to also show the displaymember of the current row on a separate part of my form when the cell is double-clicked.

Example:

```
private void radGvReviews_CellDoubleClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Row.Cells["ContractorID"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Unfortunately, this will only display the ValueMember for the column (i.e. 1, instead of Fred; 2, instead of Bob), and the control does not contain a definition for the "DisplayMember" or "Text" properties (where I would expect to find the value that is actually being displayed on screen).

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
void radGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewComboBoxColumn comboCol = e.Column as GridViewComboBoxColumn;
    if (comboCol != null)
    {
        DataTable source = comboCol.DataSource as DataTable;
        foreach (DataRow row in source.Rows)
        {
            if (row["ContractorID"].Equals(e.Value))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(row["ContractorName"].ToString());
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the `GridViewComboBoxColumn` for that cell. Then access the DisplayMember property

**Edit:** Updated Sample

```
private void radGvReviews_CellDoubleClick(object sender, GridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     GridViewComboBoxColumn combo = radGvReviews.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as GridViewComboBoxColumn;
     if (combo != null)
     {
              MessageBox.Show(combo.DisplayMember);
     }
}
```

Comment: Michael, I failed to mention that I have tried your code sample previously. When attempted, I receive a "Cannot convert type 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewCellInfo' to 'Telerik.WinControls.UI.GridViewComboBoxColumn' via a reference conversion, etc., etc." Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the documentation for CellDoubleClick](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/telerik.wincontrols.gridview-telerik.wincontrols.ui.radgridview-celldoubleclick_ev.html). It seems to tell me that you can get the text you want from `e.Value`